# Abort the execution of a ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am sending an ajax request which is called on change event of a select box.Now what I want is that when a new request is sent to server, it will abort all the previous ajax requests as otherwise there will be a lot of ajax requests executing at the same time.I just want to execute only the latest request.

All help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Just store the XMLHttpRequests in an array and abort them one by one.